# setInterval() object's method call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to call an object method within a `setInterval()` timer, but without success.
The method gets called once when creating the Object is created. Changes in the method declaration only gave me errors that update isn't a function at all.

Is this a problem of function accessibility or did i make a general structure mistake?

```js
    window.viz = new VizOne("test.json");
    setInterval(viz.updateViz(), 5000);
    

    
//one object for each viz, each has a setup and an update method
    function VizOne(dataFile){
        var file = dataFile;
        var data = [];
        var s = Snap(500,100);
        
        var fullLength = 0;
        var allRects = [];
        
        $.getJSON(file, function( rawData ) {
            var i = 0;        
            $.each( rawData, function( key, val ) {
                data[i] = val;
                i++;
            })                
        }).done(function() {        
            for(i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
                allRects.push(s.rect(fullLength, 0, data[i],100)
                               .attr({fill: "#bada55", opacity: Math.random()})
                                   );
                                       
                console.log("x: "+ fullLength +", value: "+ data[i]);
                fullLength= fullLength+parseInt(data[i]);
            }
        });
           
        //method
        this.updateViz = function() {            
            $.getJSON(file, function( rawData ) {
                var i = 0;        
                $.each( rawData, function( key, val ) {
                    data[i] = val;
                    i++;
                })                
            }).done(function() {        
                console.log("update vizOne")
                for(i = 0; i<allRects.length; i++){
                    allRects[i].animate({opacity: Math.random()},3000);                                    
                    }

                   })                                                            
            }        
    };
```

Comment: `setInterval(viz.updateViz, 5000);`  Lose the `()`.  You want to pass the function itself, not call it and pass its return value (`undefined`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `setInterval` needs to be a *function*.

You are **calling** `viz.updateViz()` and passing the *return value* (which is undefined).

Since `updateViz` depends on being called in the right context (it uses `this` internally), you need to create a new function that will call it in the right context.

```
setInterval(viz.updateViz.bind(viz), 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `()` after a method name will call the method immediately and the return value of the method call will be passed as an argument to `setInterval`. Get rid of the `()` and just pass the function reference.

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval(viz.updateViz(), 5000);` is calling the result of `viz.updateViz()`, but you would like instead write `setInterval(viz.updateViz, 5000);`